# Supporting multiple MIME types in a simple HTTP server

Tags: c, linux, http, server, mime-types

I'm programming a simple HTTP server in C. So far, my server only supports text/html. I'm trying to add more functionalities to it by supporting additional MIME types (more precisely: text /css, text/javascript, image/jpg, image/png, font/woff2). For html files, I simply used fseek() and ftell() to determine the size of the file and read(), write() to read the file into a buffer and send it to the client. Now, I have the following questions:

1.Can I treat js, css, and woff2 files the exact same as html files (figuring size, reading, and sending)?
2.For binary files (images), what differences am I expected to make? Can I still use fseek() and ftell() to determine the size? Let's say I used fread(), can I use the return value as the file length? Is fwrite() really better than write() for binary files? Do I have to encode the image file before sending (I checked the RFC but I can't find any definite answer)? Should I include the "Content-Transfer-Encoding", or is it optional?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to encode the image file before sending (I checked the RFC but I can't find any definite answer)? Should I include the "Content-Transfer-Encoding", or is it optional?

No you don't need any encoding, and, FWIW, there is no Content-Transfer-Encoding field in HTTP.